# How get BaseType from IdentifierNameSyntax

Tags: c#, roslyn

I try make analyser which will detect BaseType `IB` from class `A` inside `list.Add(typeof(A));`. I have `A` as `IdentifierNameSyntax` but there is not method for getting base `IB`. Or exist? Can you help me?

```
class Consolidator
{
...
    public void Warner()
    {
        list.Add(typeof(A));
    }
...
}

class A : IB
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Roslyn analyzer, you need to use the SemanticModel to bind the thing inside the typeof. Call SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo() and that'll give you an INamedTypeSymbol. From there you can inspect the base types.

Comment: Thanks @JasonMalinowski, it works with `Interfaces` call too :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the `Type.BaseType` Property. For more details check out the MSDN documentation: [Type.BaseType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.basetype?view=net-5.0)

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var variable = new A();
        Console.WriteLine(variable.GetType().BaseType);
    }
}
class IB
{
//
}

class A : IB
{
//
}
```

Comment: You might also want to look at `Type.IsAssignableFrom` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?view=net-5.0

Comment: I believe the original questioner is asking about doing this in a Roslyn analyzer, where System.Type isn't available.